# not able to execute php file in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, google-chrome-extension

Currently I'm new to chrome extension development .
what i want to do is , I'll take url from address bar and feed to my database . so i created a simple html file "popup.html" and want to send that data to script.php file using post method ..
but whenever i click on submit button , nothing happens..

***popup.html***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>KnowPhish</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
body{
width:300px;
height:200px;
}
</style>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


  <h4>My First extension Page.</h4>
  <p>This is some text.</p> 
<p id="demo"></p>

  <form id="form1"  method="post" action="http://localhost/extension/script.php" autocomplete="off" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input class="search-term required" id="in1" type="text" height="40px" name="url" placeholder="Type your search URL here" title="* Please enter a search URL!" autocomplete="off">
    
   </form>
   
 <button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
   chrome.tabs.query({
active: true,
lastFocusedWindow: true
}, function(tabs) {
var tab = tabs[0];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = tab.url;
document.getElementById("in1").value = tab.url;
 });
```

***manifest.json***

```
 {
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "KnowPhish",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Building an Extension!",
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": ["tabs","activeTab","http://localhost/*"]
}
```

***script.php***

```
   <pre><?php
var_dump($_POST);
?></pre>
```

even i tried with this simple code .. but this also didn't execute. Doing all this on my localhost.. 
plzzzz anyone help .It will be great help. thankyou..

Comment: The first thing to do is to check the devtools console. The popup is a separate page so it has its own separate devtools: right-click the popup, then click "inspect".

Comment: yes ,  i tried ..console remains blank.

Comment: It's working for me. But anyway this is probably not what you want because submitting a form will replace the entire popup page with the response from your server. It's better to use `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` from your script to post the data.

Comment: i also tried this method , working fine in browser with localhost..but when i try those files in my chrome extension ,nothing happens ..Dont know why. actually  any php script is not executing only in extension , but woring fine in browser..

Comment: Did you open the correct devtools? It's separate in the popup.

Comment: thankyou so much .. I got the error :)